# Hiding a view using @Biding variable with animation

Tags: animation, swiftui, binding

I am trying to show a view on top of another view. Showing the custom view with animation works fine, but I have a problem with hiding it with animation. here is the code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
        @State private var showMenu = false
                CircleButton(image: "line.3.horizontal", action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) { showMenu.toggle() }
                })
                .padding(.bottom)
                .offset(y: 30)
                
                //Showing main menu
                if showMenu { MenuView(isVisible: $showMenu) }
    }
}
```

Main Menu View:

```
struct MenuView: View {

    @Binding var isVisible: Bool

var body: some View {
ZStack {
    Button("Close") {
    isVisible.toggle()
    }
  }
 }
```

No I tried several approaches such as:

```
  withAnimation(.easeInOut) { isVisible.toggle() }
```

or

```
.opacity(isVisible? 1 : 0)
.animation(.easeInOut, value: isVisible)
```

or even tried with animatableData:

```
var animatableData: Bool {
    get { isVisible }
    set { isVisible = newValue }
}
```

and non of those worked!. when I tap the close button it just disappears with no animation, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in container and give it animation, so container animates view appear/disappear, like

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
  ZStack {    // 1) container
      CircleButton(image: "line.3.horizontal", action: {
                  showMenu.toggle()  // << bonus: no need animation here !!
             })
             .padding(.bottom)
         .offset(y: 30)

    //Showing main menu
    if showMenu { MenuView(isVisible: $showMenu) } // 2) optional view
  }
  .animation(.easeInOut, value: showMenu)   // 3) animation
```

Comment: Thanks but same result! it just hides the view without animation

Comment: Tested as works. I can assume your real code differs from provided or you did not adapt code provided in answer completely as specified.

Comment: BTW, this `@State private var showMenu = false` should be out of body, but I think it is just a typo.

Comment: I have created a test view and works fine not sure why this doesn't work!
please check these files:
https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0a6LhAFesVzfPHPh-1iems6jQ#Archive